# Xamarin TranslateTo uses independent units

Tags: xamarin

It appears that `TranslateTo` uses device independent units.  How can I obtain the height and width of the current screen in these same units to avoid moving off the screen?

`Current.MainPage.Width/Height` appears to give pixels.  `App.ScreenWidth` (from Adding a Pan Gesture Recognizer) appears to be undefined in my App.  `this.Content.Width` appears again to be in pixels.

I want to automate movement of an image without sending it off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms defines its own device-independent units

- iOS: 160 units to the inch
- Android: 160 units to the inch
- Windows Phone: assume 240 units

`VisualElement` classes defines two properties named Width and Height that provide the rendered dimension of views, layouts, and pages in these device-independent units.

So for a `Page` subclass you can monitor its size (and when orientation changes and thus the Width/Height change):

```
void OnPageSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)     
{         
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{Width}:{Height}");
}
```

Apply the event in the Page's constructor:

```
SizeChanged += OnPageSizeChanged;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I was misunderstanding the numbers I was seeing from Width/Height.  They are device-independent.  My bigger problem was understanding how TranslateTo doesn't actually change the "base" location of the object, so consecutive TranslateTo's must be cumulative if the object is to appear to move across the screen in starts and stops.  Thanks again